# When I try to create a Stripe Customer using java sdk, it is throwing "Invalid Object"

Tags: java, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I am trying to create a Stripe Customer with address and I not able to do so because it ends up throwing invalid object error. If I remove the address I am able to create the customer. But my requirement is to create the customer with his/her address.

This is the code that I am trying to execute.

```
Address address = new Address();
address.setPostalCode("250532");
address.setState("Maharashtra");
address.setLine2("20/2, Ganesh Street");
address.setCity("Mumbai");
address.setCountry("IN");

Map<String, Object> customerParams = new HashMap<>();

customerParams.put("email", "test@gmail.com");
customerParams.put("name", "Radhey");
customerParams.put("description", "Test Customer");
customerParams.put("address", address);
customerParams.put("source", token);
Customer customer = Customer.create(customerParams);
```

It is throwing invalid object error on the last line of the code.

Below given is the stacktrace:

```
com.stripe.exception.InvalidRequestException: Invalid object
    at com.stripe.net.LiveStripeResponseGetter.handleAPIError(LiveStripeResponseGetter.java:645)
    at com.stripe.net.LiveStripeResponseGetter._request(LiveStripeResponseGetter.java:490)
    at com.stripe.net.LiveStripeResponseGetter.request(LiveStripeResponseGetter.java:73)
    at com.stripe.net.APIResource.request(APIResource.java:161)
    at com.stripe.model.Customer.create(Customer.java:380)
    at com.stripe.model.Customer.create(Customer.java:265)
    at stripe.Test.chargeCreditCard(Test.java:51)
    at stripe.Test.main(Test.java:19)
```

Comment: show complete stack trace

Comment: I updated the question. Please take a look.

Comment: Have you considered attempting to use the new `builder` syntax that is in the current Stripe docs?  It matches with the current Java doc which includes the specifications when providing an Address while creating a Customer
https://stripe.dev/stripe-java/com/stripe/param/CustomerCreateParams.Address.html

Comment: @RyanM Thanks, that solved the problem for me. Could you post this as an answer so that I can accept that as a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution by @RyanM in the comment section worked for me.

> Have you considered attempting to use the new builder syntax that is
> in the current Stripe docs? It matches with the current Java doc which
> includes the specifications when providing an Address while creating a
> Customer
> https://stripe.dev/stripe-java/com/stripe/param/CustomerCreateParams.Address.html